# Why I am not able to remove the charcter using sed?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have a json file and am trying to remove the characters `\r` using `sed`, but I am not getting any output.

Here is the document

```
{"dom":"fff.dd",[{"em":"Fade@jaffer.co\r"}]}
{"dom":"fff.dd",[{"em":"Fade@jaffer.co"},{"em":"Lead@jaffer.co\r"}]}
```

The `sed` command I am using is:

```
sed 's/\r//' input.json
```

There is no error and the output what I am getting is the original file with the characters `\r` still there, as if no operation has been performed on the file.

Please let me know if I am wrong somewhere in using the command, and what is the right way to do this.

Comment: Command-line inputs and other contexts are subject to rendering before processing arguments in context with command. Here are examples showing single vs. double quotes. 
`sed "s/\\\r//g" scratch
{"dom":"fff.dd",[{"em":"Fade@jaffer.co"}]}
{"dom":"fff.dd",[{"em":"Fade@jaffer.co"},{"em":"Lead@jaffer.co"}]}

sed 's/\\\r//g' scratch
{"dom":"fff.dd",[{"em":"Fade@jaffer.co\r"}]}
{"dom":"fff.dd",[{"em":"Fade@jaffer.co"},{"em":"Lead@jaffer.co\r"}]}

sed 's/\\r//g' scratch
{"dom":"fff.dd",[{"em":"Fade@jaffer.co"}]}
{"dom":"fff.dd",[{"em":"Fade@jaffer.co"},{"em":"Lead@jaffer.co"}]}
`

Comment: @BenjaminBrink Thank you for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need another backslash:

```
sed 's/\\r//' input.json
```

This is because `sed` interprets `\r` as a line return (character `\U0E`), but interprets `\\r` as a backslash and small r (two characters `\U5C\U72`).